# Group multiple file descriptors to one "virtual" file descriptor for exporting an FD over an API

Tags: linux, unix, event-handling, file-descriptor

If a subsystem has event handling capabilities, then it is common in the Unix/Linux world to add an API call to that subsystem to allow for exposing a file descriptor so that said event handling can be integrated into existing mainloops that use something like poll() or select(). For example, in Wayland, there's wl_display_get_fd(). If that FD shows activity, wl_display_read_events() and friends can be called.

This works trivially if that subsystem internally has exactly one FD. But what if there are multiple FDs that need to be watched for events?

I only see two solutions:

1. Expose *all* FDs. However, I am not aware of any API that does that.
2. Expose some sort of "virtual" FD that is in some way coupled to the internal, "real" FDs. Once a real FD receives data and is marked as readable, then so is that virtual FD. Once a real FD can be written to, then the virtual FD is automatically marked as writable etc.

#2 sounds cleaner to me. Is it possible to do that? Or are there better ways to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically working with Linux, then you can use the `epoll` mechanism.  You first create an `epoll` instance with

```c
int fd;

fd = epoll_create(1); // The argument is legacy and doesn't matter.  It just has to be positive.
```

After that, you can add selectors that you care about.

```c
if ( epoll_ctl(fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, some_file_descriptor, NULL) != 0 ) {
    // handle error
}
```

That last argument can actually contain data that want passed back to you later when one of your file descriptors becomes ready.  Check the man page for the specifics.

You can inquire about any ready descriptors using `epoll_wait` or `epoll_pwait`.